# Are there a standard function for checking whether a number is in the range?

Tags: c++

I am a C++ student.

In order to increase my programming speed in school quizzes, I wonder there is a standard function for me to check whether a number is in the range I give.

```
I know it must be a stupid question. 
Since typing "if ((x>A)&&(X<B))" is quite unefficient, 
if there is a standard function like 
if (inrge(-3,18,99))    :    inrge(double A, double x, double B)" 
or other faster ways to do the same, It will be more efficient.
```

---

***Thank you for your attention***

Comment: What's wrong with `x > A && x < B`?

Comment: Hey,

I am unsure why you would need a dedicated function for that.
A simple if statement would do. Is there a specific reason you're asking this?

Comment: Given that both ends of the range will sometimes be included, sometimes excluded, you'd need either four different functions, or extra arguments to specify just which comparison you want. Either way, that seems like it would cause a lot of unnecessary confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not a standard function (to my knowledge anyway). Although it would be trivial to make one.

```
bool rangeCheck(int number, int min, int max)
{
    return min < number && number < max;
}
```